# Using MSP430 with Energia

Tags: msp430, energia

I've had a MSP430 for a very long time, but only recently got interested in it.

The chip in my MSP430 is a MSP430G2231, which according to http://energia.nu/Guide_MSP430LaunchPad.html I should be able to use with Energia.

But it doesn't show up in the board list, and when I try to compile the blink sample I get this error.

> Energia: 1.6.10E18 (Windows 10), Board: "MSP-EXP430G2553LP"
>
> :0:12: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
>   [enabled by default]
>
> Sketch uses 760 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 16,384
>   bytes. Global variables use 20 bytes (3%) of dynamic memory, leaving
>   492 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 512 bytes. MSPDebug version
>   0.22 - debugging tool for MSP430 MCUs Copyright (C) 2009-2013 Daniel Beer  This is free software; see the source for
>   copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> usbutil: unable to find a device matching 0451:f432 An error occurred
>   while uploading the sketch
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Not sure what I'm missing...

**Device info:**

[image]

**New details:**
Contacted the developer, and they sent me this:

> Please see the work-around for this in this thread:
>   http://forum.43oh.com/topic/9848-energia-1610r18-windows-7-launchpad-msp430g2553-dont-load-sketch/?p=74156
>
> Will be fixed in the next core release.

Which has a work around to get this fixed:

1. copy \hardware\tools\DSLite\DebugServer\drivers\MSP430.dll to \hardware\tools\msp430\bin\
2. edit \hardware\energia\msp430\boards.txt an change the 2 occurrences of rf2500 with tilib
3. restart energia and you should be able to upload to the MSP-EXP430G2 with MSP430G2553.

Now I'm getting this error:

> MSP430_GetNumberOfUsbIfs
>   MSP430_GetNameOfUsbIf
>   Found FET: HID0016:COM5
>   MSP430_Initialize: HID0016:COM5
>   Firmware version is 20409001
>   MSP430_VCC: 3000 mV
>   MSP430_OpenDevice
>   MSP430_GetFoundDevice
>   Device: F20x2_G2x2x_G2x3x (id = 0x0035)
>   2 breakpoints available
>   MSP430_EEM_Init
>   Chip ID data: f2 01 02
>   Erasing...
>   Programming...
>   Writing  842 bytes at c000...
>   tilib: MSP430_Memory: Could not write device memory (error = 7)
>   MSP430_Run
>   ihex: error on line 55
>   tilib: MSP430_Run: Could not run device (to breakpoint) (error = 17)
>   MSP430_Close
>   the selected serial port MSP430_Close  does not exist or
>   your board is not connected

Comment: "MSP430" is the name of a CPU architecture, with hundreds of models. What board do you have?

Comment: @CL. It just says MSP430G2 Rev 1.3 on top...  the chip is the MSP430G2231, the bottom has a sticker that says Rev 1.4(?) And another says 100706073. When I program it from CCS I just use the number on the chip and it works. I just like the Arduino language better.

Comment: Okay, "MSP-EXP430G2553LP" is the correct board, and G2231 is the correct chip. But "unable to find a device matching 0451:f432" means that the board was not found. Does it show up in Device Manager? If yes, what are its hardware IDs?

Comment: @CL. I added a screenshot of my device manager and stuff. I don't know if that's the ID you mean, or if there is another that I need...

Comment: There should be another port besides the Application UART. Use View/Devices by Connection. You can find the hardware IDs in the device's properties.

Comment: Right-click in the device manager and select "View hidden devices"

Comment: @CL. Got some progress after a reply from the developer. Now I'm getting an error about not being able to write to c000, which seems like a problem because it's outside of the chips address range.

Comment: So I'm kinda thinking it'll be better to just give up on this board and get a couple cheap Arduino knock offs. It only puts out 3.3V which means I have to alter my circuit, and I can't get it to keep a program in memory once power is removed. I'm just not sure if I should delete the question or self answer with this and close it...